# C# How to P/Invoke NtRaiseHardError

Tags: c#, c++-cli, pinvoke, blue-screen-of-death

The following C++ code causes a bluescreen.

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <Windows.h>

    #pragma comment(lib, "ntdll.lib")


    using namespace std;


    EXTERN_C NTSTATUS NTAPI RtlAdjustPrivilege(ULONG, BOOLEAN, BOOLEAN, PBOOLEAN);

    EXTERN_C NTSTATUS NTAPI NtRaiseHardError(NTSTATUS, ULONG, ULONG, PULONG_PTR, ULONG, PULONG);

    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
        BOOLEAN bl;
        RtlAdjustPrivilege(19, TRUE, FALSE, &bl);
        unsigned long response;
        NtRaiseHardError(STATUS_ASSERTION_FAILURE, 0, 0, 0, 6, &response);
        return 0;
    }
```

I want to use C# for this so I tried to use P/Invoke. But it doesn't work. The problem is properly at the NtRaiseHardError signature. I haven't found anything about it online (pinvoke.net for example doesn't show NtRaiseHardError because it is undocumented.)
This is what I tried:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.IO;

    namespace BSCS
    {
        class Program
        {
            private static ulong STATUS_ASSERTION_FAILURE = 0xC0000420;

            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Adjusting privileges");
                RtlAdjustPrivilege(19, true, false, out bool previousValue);
                Console.WriteLine("Triggering BSOD");
                NtRaiseHardError(STATUS_ASSERTION_FAILURE, 0, 0, 0, 6, out ulong oul);
                Console.WriteLine("Done");
            }

            [DllImport("ntdll.dll")]
            private static extern IntPtr RtlAdjustPrivilege(int Privilege, bool bEnablePrivilege, bool IsThreadPrivilege,
                out bool PreviousValue);

            [DllImport("ntdll.dll")]
            private static extern IntPtr NtRaiseHardError(ulong status, ulong ul, ulong ul2, ulong ul3, ulong ul4, out ulong oul);
        }
    }
```

Comment: And this works in user mode?

Comment: Anyway where  is the definition, it looks like some of your parameters maybe wrong  https://undocumented.ntinternals.net/index.html?page=UserMode%2FUndocumented%20Functions%2FError%2FNtRaiseHardError.html

Comment: @MichaelRandall in C++ yes

Comment: @MichaelRandall I'm no expert with P/Invoke. I don't know what to use for NTSTATUS, PULONG_PTR and PULONG.

Comment: Your signature in for the privilege has an int as it's first argument however the signature in he c++ has a ulong for the first argument. Not sure if that makes a difference but I thought I'd point it out

Comment: @Dave doesn't work either but I edited the question

Comment: @dave both are 32 bit types

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both of your pinvoke declarations are wrong.  Principally your use of C# `ulong` which is a 64 bit type. The C++ `long` type is 32 bits in Windows.

I'd declare them like this

```
[DllImport("ntdll.dll")]
private static extern uint RtlAdjustPrivilege(
    int Privilege, 
    bool bEnablePrivilege, 
    bool IsThreadPrivilege,
    out bool PreviousValue
);

[DllImport("ntdll.dll")]
private static extern uint NtRaiseHardError(
    uint ErrorStatus, 
    uint NumberOfParameters, 
    uint UnicodeStringParameterMask, 
    IntPtr Parameters, 
    uint ValidResponseOption, 
    out uint Response
);
```

I've taken a short cut with the `PULONG_PTR`. Because you are passing the null pointer it's easier to declare it as `IntPtr` and pass `IntPtr.Zero`.

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm. Sadly I can't upvote :) Could you replace these ul, ul2, ul3, ... with this?          [DllImport("ntdll.dll")]
        private static extern uint NtRaiseHardError(uint ErrorStatus, uint NumberOfParameters, uint UnicodeStringParameterMask,
            IntPtr Parameters, uint ValidResponseOption, out uint Response);

Comment: You can name the arguments as you please

Comment: Sure, but this might be a bit confusing

Comment: OK, but they were your names. You can edit my answer. It will be a suggested edit. I'll accept it.