# Can someone explain RtlAdjustPrivilege

Tags: c#, c, function, bsod, ntdll

I have knowledge of java and python ,but any language containing C in its name is so hard to understand and learn. Recently i was trying to create BSOD in windows using NtRaiseHardError and after few (unsuccessful) tries in c++ I turned to c#.

Using code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49207263/c-sharp-how-to-p-invoke-ntraiseharderror) i was able to make a program and cause bsod. Later i tried to fully understand the code but i can not understand what RtlAdjustPrivilege is doing.

I see that it is some kind of privilege changing but while program is running i see no administrator password prompts despite the fact that i am using user account so i believe that it is not escalating to admin privileges. If someone know what exactly this function does or how it works please explain it. This is how it is implemented:

To import it:

```
[DllImport("ntdll.dll")]
private static extern uint RtlAdjustPrivilege
(
    int Privilege,
    bool bEnablePrivilege,
    bool IsThreadPrivilege,
    out bool PreviousValue
);
```

And later use it:

```
RtlAdjustPrivilege(19, true, false, out bool previousValue);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

19 is `SE_SHUTDOWN_PRIVILEGE` - declared in *wdm.h*.

`RtlAdjustPrivilege` open current process (if *IsThreadPrivilege := false* ) or current thread (if *IsThreadPrivilege := true* )token, then call `ZwAdjustPrivilegeToken` (`AdjustTokenPrivileges` is thin shell over this api) and finally close open token.

The `ZwAdjustPrivilegeToken` (`AdjustTokenPrivileges`) function enables or disables privileges in the specified access token. but privilege must be already in token

Comment: @JustHobby - yes. correct. only enable or disable single privilege. if want more - better call `AdjustTokenPrivileges`

Comment: Thanks for help @RbMm

Comment: @JustHobby of course this api "undocumented", but exported from ntdll.dll in all windows versions and by my opinion - always will be exported. it allow more simply adjust single privilege. we need more - of course `AdjustTokenPrivileges`(or `ZwAdjustPrivilegeToken`) more efficient here, but several time call `RtlAdjustPrivilege` also not too bad. and function return `NTSATUS` - `long` (can assume and `int`- this is the same), but not `uint` - in sense this is signed result and we compare it for >= 0 (ok) or (<0 fail)

Comment: I know it is "undocumented" but it was simple to call so i used it any way. I am not very got at windows programming but i think i will use AdjustTokenPrivileges next time if i can get same results. Thanks again.